# Missing or Invalid DMARC Record in server mail

Tags: email-server, mx-record, dmarc, webmin

my main problem is that I am not receiving mails to my domain after adding an MX Server to my domain for mailing in Webmin, and 
After testing a server by mxtoolbox.com tool, I found that there is problem in DMARC Records,
it says Missing or Invalid Record like in the picture below:
[image]

I added this DMARC Record but there is nothing changed
is there somthing missing or wrong in my configuration

```
...    
magicmax.ca.    IN  A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
www.magicmax.ca.    IN  A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ftp.magicmax.ca.    IN  A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
m.magicmax.ca.  IN  A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
localhost.magicmax.ca.  IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.magicmax.ca.    IN  A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
admin.magicmax.ca.  IN  A   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
mail.magicmax.ca.   IN  MX  1 magicmax.ca. 
...
_dmarc.magicmax.ca. IN  TXT "v=DMARC1; pct=100; ruf=mailto:dmarc_afrf@mail.magicmax.ca; rua=mailto:dmarc_agg@mail.magicmax.ca; p=quarantine; adkim=r; aspf=r"
```

Comment: Your domain magicmax.ca. is registered to ns19.domaincontrol.com. and 
ns20.domaincontrol.com. as nameservers, are you creating the DMARC record in the correct control panel?

Comment: According to https://dmarc.org/2016/07/common-problems-with-dmarc-records/ : `The “p=” policy tag must appear immediately following the “v=” tag.`

Answer (score 1):

After about a week or so you might see the issue in a dmarc report.

But until then you'll want to add the IP of your webmin server to your spf record, or configure a authenticated relay host.

https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/magicmax.ca

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your TXT records

`example.com._report._dmarc.example.com TXT v=DMARC1;`

`_dmarc.example.com TXT v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@example.com; ruf=mailto:postmaster@example.com; fo=1;`

don't forget to replace example.com with your domain